# SQL - Number of minutes in a month given month number

Tags: sql-server

I have a MS SQL table which contains a column containing month numbers (stored as an int).

I would like to get the number of minutes in the month using the month number.

After looking through Stack Overflow I came across the following code which I thought I could adapt to tell me the number of minutes by replacing the word `DAY` with `MINUTE` but to no avail.

```
DECLARE @ADate DATETIME
SET @ADate = GETDATE()
SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(@ADate)) AS DaysInMonth
```

The month is a 1 or 2 digit int depending on the month.

UPDATE:

I do have the year as well stored in another column.

Comment: The number of minutes of the month also depends on the year (for leap february). So will need to know the year also for this case.

Comment: @EzLo your right.  Didnt think about that.  I do have the year as well.

Comment: If you want to get a date difference use `DATEDIFF`. You are looking for the difference between the first day of a month and the first day of the *next* month

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for this it has made me think about it differently.  I can combine the month and year and using 'DATEDIFF' i can get the number of minutes.

Comment: BTW why are you looking for this? How are you going to use it? You could avoid this if you used a Calendar table that included the number of minutes per day. After that, calculating the number of minutes in any timespan would be a simple `SUM()`.

Comment: @Silentbob you should probably use the calendar table anyway - what about DST changes? You can't calculate that using the date only, you'd need to include the offset change. Otherwise you'd end up with a ±60 minutes error twice a year

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the advice I will look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF` with `MINUTE`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Month') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Month

CREATE TABLE #Month (
    MonthNumber INT,
    Year INT)

INSERT INTO #Month (
    MonthNumber,
    Year)
VALUES
    (1, 2018),
    (2, 2018),
    (2, 2016), -- Leap
    (12, 2018)

SELECT
    M.MonthNumber,
    M.Year,
    FirstDay = DATEFROMPARTS(M.Year, M.MonthNumber, 1),
    FirstDayNextMonth = DATEADD(
        MONTH, 
        1, 
        DATEFROMPARTS(M.Year, M.MonthNumber, 1)),
    Minutes = DATEDIFF(
        MINUTE,
        DATEFROMPARTS(M.Year, M.MonthNumber, 1),                    -- FirstDay
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(M.Year, M.MonthNumber, 1))) -- FirstDayNextMonth
FROM
    #Month AS M
```

Results:

```
MonthNumber Year    FirstDay    FirstDayNextMonth   Minutes
1           2018    2018-01-01  2018-02-01          44640
2           2018    2018-02-01  2018-03-01          40320
2           2016    2016-02-01  2016-03-01          41760
12          2018    2018-12-01  2019-01-01          44640
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't cover summer/winter time changes. If the number of minutes is actually important one would need to include the *offset* change.

Answer (score 1):

That's a deceptively tricky question. It's not only that the number of days in February changes in leap years. The number of *hours* in a date changes during the transition to Summer/Winter time. To calculate the correct difference in minutes between two dates you need to know the correct time offset as well.

Instead of looking up the offset for each date though, you can use the *timezone*. The timezone information contains all the rules needed to calculate the time offset for past and future dates, provided the OS's timezone information is kept up to date.

SQL Server 2016 and later support timezones with the [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression :

For example these queries:

```
select datetimefromparts(2018,3,25,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE 'E. Europe Standard Time'
select datetimefromparts(2018,3,26,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE 'E. Europe Standard Time'
```

Return

```
2018-03-25 00:00:00.000 +02:00
2018-03-26 00:00:00.000 +03:00
```

March 25 had 23 hours instead of 24. The difference of the two days in minutes is 1380 instead of the usual 1440:

```
select datediff(mi, 
    datetimefromparts(2018,3,25,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE 'E. Europe Standard Time',
    datetimefromparts(2018,3,26,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE 'E. Europe Standard Time')

-----
1380
```

You can pass the timezone name as a parameter :

```
declare @mytimezone nvarchar(40)='E. Europe Standard Time'

select datetimefromparts(2018,3,25,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE @mytimezone
select datetimefromparts(2018,3,26,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE @mytimezone
```

To calculate the correct number of minutes in a month, you could use the difference in minutes between the current and the next month's 1st day on a specific timezone with `AT TIME ZONE`. This would ensure the correct offsets are used.

A query that calculates the difference in minutes correctly could look like this :

```
declare @mytimezone nvarchar(40)='E. Europe Standard Time'

select year,month,
    datediff(mi,    
        datetimefromparts(M.Year,M.Month,1,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE @mytimezone,
        dateadd(MONTH,1,datetimefromparts(M.Year,M.Month,1,0,0,0,0)) at TIME ZONE @mytimezone
        )
from (values 
        (2016,2),
        (2018,1),
        (2018,2),
        (2018,3),
        (2018,4),
        (2018,5),
        (2018,6),
        (2018,7),
        (2018,8),
        (2018,9),
        (2018,10),
        (2018,11),
        (2018,12) ) M(Year,Month)
```

You can create a function to calculate the minutes. Either a scalar function that can be used in the `SELECT` clause  :

```
CREATE FUNCTION MinutesInMonth
(
    @Year INT,
    @Month INT,
    @timezone nvarchar(40)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN 
    Return 
        datediff(mi,    
            datetimefromparts(@year,@month,1,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE @timezone,
            dateadd(MONTH,1,datetimefromparts(@year,@month,1,0,0,0,0)) at TIME ZONE @timezone
            )
END

...

select year,month,dbo.MinutesInMonth(year,month,@mytimezone)
from (values 
        (2018,10),
        (2018,11),
        (2018,12)
        ) M(Year,Month)
```

Or an inline table function that can be used in the FROM clause and gets inlined in the query itself :

```
CREATE FUNCTION MinutesInMonth
(
    @Year INT,
    @Month INT,
    @timezone nvarchar(40)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
RETURN (select datediff(mi, 
               datetimefromparts(@year,@month,1,0,0,0,0) at TIME ZONE @timezone,
               dateadd(MONTH,1,datetimefromparts(@year,@month,1,0,0,0,0)) 
               At TIME ZONE @timezone) as Minutes
        )



select year,month,Minutes
from (values 
        (2016,2),
        (2018,1),
        (2018,2),
        (2018,3),
        (2018,4),
        (2018,5),
        (2018,6),
        (2018,7),
        (2018,8),
        (2018,9),
        (2018,10),
        (2018,11),
        (2018,12)
        ) M(Year,Month)
        cross apply dbo.MinutesInMonth(year,month,@mytimezone)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :-

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016, @Month INT = 2;

DECLARE @Date DATE = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) AT TIME ZONE 'Sri Lanka Standard Time';

SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(@Date)) * 24 * 60;
```

Alternatively you can create a scalar function as follows:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMinutesOfMonth
(
    @Year INT,
    @Month INT,
    @TimeZone VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MinutesOfMonth INT, @CurrentTimeZone VARCHAR(50);

    EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
    'TimeZoneKeyName',@CurrentTimeZone OUT;

    SET @TimeZone = ISNULL((SELECT [name] FROM SYS.time_zone_info WHERE [name] = @TimeZone), @CurrentTimeZone)

    DECLARE @Date DATE = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) AT TIME ZONE @TimeZone;

    SELECT @MinutesOfMonth = DAY(EOMONTH(@Date)) * 24 * 60;

    RETURN @MinutesOfMonth;
END
GO
```

and use  it as:-

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016, @Month INT = 2;

SELECT dbo.GetMinutesOfMonth(@Year, @Month, 'Sri Lanka Standard Time');
```

If the timezone of the current machine is same as the dates being considered, you may use the function as follows:-

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016, @Month INT = 2;

SELECT dbo.GetMinutesOfMonth(@Year, @Month, DEFAULT);
```

Comment: That's identical to the other incorrect answer. Leap years, summer time, leap seconds

Comment: This takes the year as an parameter and consider it within the computation. Please go through the implementation closely.

Comment: I downvoted not because it's wrong. It's wrong *and* identical to another wrong answer

Comment: When you consider the year, SQL Server will automatically do the needful regarding the leap years. This answer Is correct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please explain why this is incorrect as it takes into account the leap years as well.

Comment: I already did - *summer time*. When the change occurs the day has 1 hour more or less. Unfortunately even a date difference will return the wrong answer here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But it is not some thing that you can purely solve via a technical approch. Even if you consider the time zone for the calculation, Daylight Saving Time (DST) is a political policy and can vary time to time, country to country.

Comment: Yes it is. That's what the IANA timezone datatabase is for, libraries like NodaTime and JodaTime, the `datetimeoffset` type in SQL Server and .NET. SQL Server even introduced the [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression just for this reason. Other databases also allow you to specify the timezone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173215/discussion-between-chamika-goonetilaka-and-panagiotis-kanavos).